# Passing arguments by reference - inheritance and type resolution

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I'm having an issue with passing an object by reference. Let's say I have an object called `ViewModelBase` which is defined like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : IViewModelManager
{
    public ViewModelBase()
    {
    }

    // IViewModelManager implementation 
}
```

Then, I define another object which inherts from `ViewModelBase`:

```
public class ExternalAssetViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ExternalAssetViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Then I create a static class called `NotificationHandler`, which holds a list of view-model references, so it can properly update the view-models once a server notification is received:

```
public static class NotificationHandler
{
    private static List<ViewModelBase> viewModelReferences = new List<ViewModelBase>();

    public static void AddViewModelReference(ref ViewModelBase viewModel)
    {
        viewModelReferences.Add(viewModel);
    }
}
```

So now, every time I create a new view-model that needs to be updated, I add it to this static list:

```
ExternalAssetViewModel viewModel = new ExternalAssetViewModel();
NotificationHandler.AddViewModelReference(ref viewModel);
```

However, this fails with the following compile error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref ExternalAssetViewModel' to 'ref ViewModelBase'
```

Even though `ExternalAssetViewModel` inherits from `ViewModelBase`, so technically `ExternalAssetViewModel` is of type `ViewModelBase`. I was able to get around this by changing `AddViewModelReference` to take a generic argument, and then define a constraint for that argument:

```
public static void AddViewModelReference<T>(ref T viewModel) where T : ViewModelBase
{
    viewModelReferences.Add(viewModel);
}
```

Now the compiler is happy again. So my question is, why was the code breaking initially? Why can't the compiler realize the the object being referenced is the same type as the defined parameter?

Comment: Why are you passing a reference variable by ref anyways? I don't see a manipulation that would warrant not just passing it normally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error when passing a reference to a derived object in a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665339/error-when-passing-a-reference-to-a-derived-object-in-a-method)

Comment: @GlennCuevas Well I didn't provide all the code (for simplicity), but the object gets heavily manipulated.

Comment: @ppejovic Ah, I've been looking for that for almost an hour now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need `ref`.

Sample why `ref` don't allow your code:

```
 void Method(ref MyBase v)
 {
      v = new MyBase();
 }

 MyDerived d = null;
 Method(ref d);
```

If allowed would assign `MyBase` to `MyDerived` similar to following clearly wrong code:

```
 MyDerived d = new MyBase();
```

Comment: Your example makes perfect sense.